# How to construct a XPath to include specific elements from an HTML?

Tags: angular, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I have a table and I want only to select the buttons on that table. As we can see, there are only 4 buttons on this table:

[image]

I have created the following ***Xpath*** to filter out these ***4 buttons***, and no other button on the page:

```
//*[@id="studentListTable"]/thead/tr/th[contains(., "Actions")]//following::button  | //*[@id="studentListTable_info"]//preceding::button
```

- The @id="studentListTable_info"refers to the Text "Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries".

But this is not working.
This XPath is actually locating all the buttons on the page irrespective of the buttons location.

***What is wrong here?***

***How can I fix it so that only the four buttons are located by this expression?***

The HTML snippet :

```html
<div _ngcontent-c7="" appcard="" class="card">
    <div _ngcontent-c7="" class="card-header">
        <h5 _ngcontent-c7="">Student list <!----></h5></div>
    <ul _ngcontent-c7="" class="card-actions">
        <li _ngcontent-c7="">
            <button _ngcontent-c7="" appcardfullscreen="" class="card-action">
                <i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></button></li>
        <li _ngcontent-c7="">
            <button _ngcontent-c7="" appcardcollapse="" class="card-action icon-collapse"><i _ngcontent-c7="" class="material-icons">expand_more</i></button></li></ul>
    <!---->
    <div _ngcontent-c7="" class="card-body">
        <div id="studentListTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
            <div class="dataTables_length" id="studentListTable_length">
                <label>Show <select name="studentListTable_length" aria-controls="studentListTable" class="">
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option>
                </select> entries</label></div>
            <div id="studentListTable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                <label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="studentListTable"></label>
            </div>
            <table _ngcontent-c7="" class="table table-striped dataTable no-footer" datatable="" id="studentListTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="studentListTable_info">
            <thead _ngcontent-c7="">
            <tr _ngcontent-c7="" role="row">
                <th _ngcontent-c7="" class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="studentListTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Student ID: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 101px;">Student ID</th>
                 <th _ngcontent-c7="" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Actions" style="width: 106px;">Actions</th></tr>
            </thead><!----><tbody _ngcontent-c7=""><!---->
            <tr _ngcontent-c7="" role="row" class="odd">
                <td _ngcontent-c7="" class="sorting_1">123456</td>
                 <td _ngcontent-c7="">
                    <a href="unsafe:javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons text-warning">info</i> Not Started</a></td>
                <td _ngcontent-c7="">Null</td>
                <td _ngcontent-c7="" class="text-left"><!----><div _ngcontent-c7="">
                    <button _ngcontent-c7="" class="btn btn-sm btn-sm-action mr-2 btn-outline-info" container="body" placement="left" popoverclass="btn-popover" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" type="button" tabindex="0">
                        <i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button></div><!----><!----><!----></td></tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-c7="" role="row" class="even">
                <td _ngcontent-c7="" class="sorting_1">153246</td>
                 <td _ngcontent-c7=""><a href="unsafe:javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-unlock mr-2"></i>In Progress</a></td>
                <td _ngcontent-c7="">Herndon MS</td>
                <td _ngcontent-c7="" class="text-left"><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c7=""><!----><div _ngcontent-c7="" class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <button _ngcontent-c7="" class="btn btn-sm btn-sm-action mr-2 btn-outline-info col" container="body" placement="left" popoverclass="btn-popover" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" type="button" tabindex="0">
                        <i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                    <button _ngcontent-c7="" class="btn btn-sm btn-sm-action mr-2 btn-outline-danger col" container="body" placement="left" popoverclass="btn-popover" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" type="button">
                        <i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></div><!----></div><!----><!----></td></tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-c7="" role="row" class="odd">
                <td _ngcontent-c7="" class="sorting_1">234135</td>
                 <td _ngcontent-c7="" class="text-left"><!----><!----><!---->
                    <div _ngcontent-c7="">
                        <button _ngcontent-c7="" class="btn btn-sm btn-sm-action mr-2 btn-outline-info" container="body" placement="left" popoverclass="btn-popover" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" type="button" tabindex="0">
                            <i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-eye"></i></button></div><!----></td></tr></tbody><!----><!----><!----></table>
            <div class="dataTables_info" id="studentListTable_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries</div>
            <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="studentListTable_paginate">
                <a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="studentListTable" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="studentListTable_previous">Previous</a>
                <span>
                    <a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="studentListTable" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
                </span>
                <a class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="studentListTable" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0" id="studentListTable_next">Next</a></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: You are selecting a certain node  and then merge all following buttons with all preceding buttons - which selects pretty much all of the buttons. I guess that what you want is to `intersect` both sets - which is only possible with XPath-2.0 or above. Currently I don't even know if the rest of the expressions is correct - can you provide the HTML/XML source sample?

Comment: Hi, I added the html snippet. Pls take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//table[@id="studentListTable" and thead/tr/th/text() =  "Actions"]/tbody/tr/td[@class="sorting_1"]
```

to select the following three items:

```
<td _ngcontent-c7="" class="sorting_1">123456</td>
<td _ngcontent-c7="" class="sorting_1">153246</td>
<td _ngcontent-c7="" class="sorting_1">234135</td>
```

To proceed further to get the four `button`s contained in these three `table`s, the following XPath will do:

```
//table[@id="studentListTable" and thead/tr/th/text() =  "Actions"]/tbody/tr/td[@class="sorting_1"]/../../tr/td//button
```

Its result consists of the following four items:

```
<button ... type="button" tabindex="0">
    <i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-arrow-right"/>
</button>
<button ... type="button" tabindex="0">
    <i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-pencil"/>
</button>
<button ... type="button">
    <i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-trash-o"/>
</button>
<button ... type="button" tabindex="0">
    <i _ngcontent-c7="" class="fa fa-eye"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Difficult to answer your first question what is wrong there.
   You are using some `|` and two different `id`s and maybe it isn't fully correct.
   And you used `thead` element in your Xpath. Despite the fact that all buttons located at `tbody`. 
   Anyway, your locator gets all HTML buttons from that page.
2. I tried to modify Xpath to following:

> //table//button

And it worked well:

[image]

However, it isn't very good ***Xpath***.
So try to bind it to some nearest `id`. After update it can be like:

> //div[@id='studentListTable_wrapper']//table//button

The result of the evaluation is the same.

And much more redundant version will be (not recomended to use, just for example reason):

> //div[@id='studentListTable_wrapper']//table/tbody/tr/td/div//button

BTW to my opinion much better is to use locators like:

> //div[@id='...']

instead of:

> //*[...]

Difficult to see if it can be the reason of incorrect select.
For sure it is much more ***readable*** and ***easier to understand*** in the future support.

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

- The *buttons* in the first and third row are within `class="odd"`
- The two *buttons* in the second row are within `class="even"`

To filter out these 4 buttons you can use the following *XPath* based solution:

```
"//table[@class='table table-striped dataTable no-footer' and @id='studentListTable']//tbody//tr[@class= 'odd' or @class='even']//td[@class='text-left']//button"
```

A snapshot of the matching result through *xpath* checker:

[image: matching_xpath]

**Note**: You havn't mentioned the *language binding* you are using so as the elements are [Angular](https://angular.io/) elements to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, the title means you want combine the 2 attempted XPath expressions to get buttons that is located after *`th` containing text "Actions"* and before *`div` with id "studentListTable_info"* :

```
//*[@id="studentListTable"]/thead/tr/th[contains(., "Actions")]//following::button[
    following::*[@id="studentListTable_info"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BUTTON`s you want are the only buttons inside the table and the table has an ID, `studentListTable`, so all you need are the children `BUTTON`s of the ID.

From the HTML you have provided, something simple like the below will work.

XPath

```
//[@id='studentListTable']//button
```

CSS selector

```
#studentListTable button
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select buttons by `Student Id` using below xpath as example with `153246` id:

```
//table[@id='studentListTable']//tr[@role='row' and ./td[@class='sorting_1' and .='153246']]//button
```